# How can I access the files used in a HTML file on a website with Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having a problem with Node.JS.

I'm trying to upload a HTML file with Node.JS (the HTML file has links to JS, JSON and CSS files) but when I turn on the server and look at the page, only what was in the HTML is written, which means there is no CSS and no JS which were working properly before I implemented the server.

Can anyone help me?

Here's the Node.JS code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static('project-folder'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('website.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("server is up");
});
```

Comment: what are the contents of `project-folder`? Also how are the css/js assets linked (what do the paths look like) in the HTML file?

Comment: @Yasio project-folder has another folder called "website" where these files are stored in. the css and js assets look something like this:  "./styles.css", "./script.js"

Comment: so, you probably need to move the css/js files to be next to the website.html file, or change the paths from "./styles.css" to "./website/styles.css"

Comment: @Yasio the files were next to the html file from the beginning. here are the errors that appear when I open the console on my browser:  `ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` for both JavaScript and jQuery (i´m using a framework for the javascript part) and `"Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."` for the CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your folder structure looks like this:

```
project-folder
  |-website
  |  |-style.css
  |  |-script.js
  |-website.html
  |-server.js
```

then the code should look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'website')));


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('website.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("server is up");
});
```

---

if it's like this:

```
project-folder
  |-website
  |  |-style.css
  |  |-script.js
  |  |-website.html
  |-server.js
```

then the code should look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'website')));


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile('website.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'website') });
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("server is up");
});
```

> Mind the path module that is required at the top

Comment: may god bless you brother
, you saved my life